# Jaxws and MTOM seems not to work

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, soapui, mtom

i want to send a docx document via a Webservice (jaxws) using MTOM.

Here is an excerpt of my wsdl:

```
<xsd:element name="createDocumentResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="docContent" type="xsd:base64Binary" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I want to use MTOM, so I annotate the webservice with @MTOM

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "de.xy.crm.services.ws...")
@MTOM(enabled = true, threshold = 1024)
public class MyWebservice....
```

The document's content is set like this:

```
byte[] convertedDocument = convert(docx);
CreateDocumentResponse response = new CreateDocumentResponse();
response.setDocContent(convertedDocument);
```

Now when I test it with SOAP UI, it seems that MTOM is enabled, but the actual content is not sent as attachment but inline:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: multipart/related;start="<rootpart*5544634d-146f-42e7-9c76-    38efd118acfc@example.jaxws.sun.com>";type="application/xop+xml";boundary="uuid:5544634d-146f-42e7-9c76-38efd118acfc";start-info="text/xml"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(8.1.3.v20120522)

--uuid:5544634d-146f-42e7-9c76-38efd118acfc
Content-Id: <rootpart*5544634d-146f-42e7-9c76-   38efd118acfc@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope   xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Header><version   xmlns="http://ws.services.crm.vkb.de/BSIWebService/">2015.2.0.qualifier</version ></S:Header><S:Body><ns2:createDocumentResponse  xmlns:ns2="http://ws.services.crm.vkb.de/BsiWebService/"> <docContent>UEsDBBQACAAIABVDnEYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbLWV y27CMBBFfyXytiKGLqqqIrDoY9kilUrdGm...
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: what's shown on the response attachments table? http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html#2-Attachments-and-Inline-Files

Comment: It says Attachments (0)

Comment: what if set "Enable Inline Files" to true in your request properties?

Comment: Its the same: Attachments (0)

Comment: @matthias at first I don't really understand your question this is why I respond about how to configure your `SOAPUI` client to send a document as `MTOM`... however your problem was about to send attachment from server to client not viceversa. I update my answer I hope that now it's more accurate `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `@MTOM` annotation in conjunction with `@WebService` annotation in your JAX-WS webService should be enough to enable `MTOM` and to send the bytes as attachment from your server to the client.

However you're using `@MTOM(enabled = true, threshold = 1024)`. In [java documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/soap/MTOM.html#threshold()) the threshold parameter has the follow description:

> Property for MTOM threshold value. When MTOM is enabled, binary data
>   above this size in bytes will be XOP encoded or sent as attachment.
>   The value of this property MUST always be >= 0. Default value is 0.

So the only thing that I think that could be wrong is that you're sending a document which its size not exceeds 1024. Try sending a bigger document, or removing `threshold` parameter on `@MTOM` annotation due this default value for it is 0 and each document will be sent as attachment.

Hope this helps,

Comment: HI albciff, thanks for your answer again. I tried setting the value to 1 and using a bigger document. However this has no impact, unfortunately. soap -ui says Attachments (0) and the base64 stream is inlined

Comment: @matthias oopps, then I don't see anything more that could be wrong... :(, anyway I will take a close look on it.

Comment: @matthias looking in your raw response the headers seems that are working correctly as MTOM: `Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`... maybe SOAPUI is making the change for you? can you try with another tool?

Comment: can you suggest another tool?

Comment: @matthias maybe you can use a TCP/IP Monitor? with it you can send the data from client to TCP Monitor an it forwards the request to the server, then server response to TCP Monitor an it forwards again the response to the client, then in the TCP Monitor you can see your request and the response. You can download a TCP Monitor from `https://code.google.com/p/tcpmon/` or for example if you're using eclipse IDE you can use the `TCP/IP Monitor` view (window>show view>other... and typing `TCP/IP Monitor'). Hope it helps.